# Javascript , JQ data type conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a list of elements which looks something like this

```html
<li class="depuy">
    <a class="comp" data-color="#66" href="#">
        Something
    </a>
</li>
```

On Backbone render, I want to add a background color to these elements taken from their data attribute. I tried to do this

```js
var som_array = $(".com a");
var som_array_length = som_array.length;
for(var i=0;i<som_array_length;i++)
{
    var som_object = som_array[i].data("color");
    console.log(som_object);
}
```

But in a console I get this message `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'data'`  but as you see it has. What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you access an item within the jQuery object using it's index, you're accessing the actual item, and not the jQuery object which contains the `data` method.

Try this:

```
$(".depuy a").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('color'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap you element in the jQuery set. Otherwise it will just be a dom element without the jQuery functions.

```
var competitors_array = $(".depuy a");
var competitors_array_length = competitors_array.length;
for(var i=0;i<competitors_array_length;i++)
{
    var competitor_object = $(competitors_array[i]).data("color"); // Like this
    console.log(competitor_object);
}
```